# Evaluate Integral $\int\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

$\int\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\ dx$

Let $u=1+x^2$

Then $du = 2x\ dx$

Here is my work.

Split integral $\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx$ + $\int\frac{x}{1+x^2}\ dx$

Integrate first integral term:

$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx=tan^{-1}x$

$\int\frac{x}{1+x^2}\cdot\frac{du}{2x} $

I am stuck when it comes to the second integral term (I hope that is the right term). I have $\frac{du}{2x}$ It does get rid of the x. Should I carry the 2 over by placing outside the second integral.

Comment: replace $1+x^2$ in the denominator by $u$

Comment: hint $x/(1+x^2)=(1/2)\partial_x \log(1+x^2)$

Comment: $\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}\cdot \frac{du}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{u}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\int \frac{1}{u}\,du=\log|u|+C$$

So, let $u=1+x^2$, $du=2x\,dx$ and ...

**SPOILER ALERT** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the answer

> $$\int\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx=\arctan(x)+\frac12 \log(1+x^2)+C$$where for the second integral, we used the HINT and substituted $u=1+x^2$, $du=2xdx$, so that $$\int\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac12\int\frac{1}{u}\,du=\frac12\log |u|+C=\frac12\log (1+x^2)+C$$

Comment: This answer is not correct-

Comment: @Cetshwayo Well, it isn't an answer ... it is only a HINT.  To assist further, I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is something of the form $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{f'}{f}$, hence:
$$ \int\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\,dx = \arctan(x)+\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2)+C.$$